# Read contents of .bin file and find string

Tags: linux

DISCLAIMER: I am very new to security and quite possibly have no idea what I'm doing.

I've been learning basic security through some practice CTFs, and I'm currently trying to capture a flag that is hidden in a .bin file. The clue is that it is too big to cat to terminal, which it clearly is. How else could I read the contents of said file and search for a specific string?

Comment: The `strings` command and using simple text editors or hex editors to view files really isn't on topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `strings` command will give you all the strings in a given binary. The searching can be done with any tooling usable for text. For example:

```
strings /path/to/file.bin | grep secret
```

or to view directly in `vi`:

```
strings /path/to/file.bin | vi -
```

or to save the result, to open it in a different text editor:

```
strings /path/to/file.bin >/path/to/file_strings.txt
```